# renewing drivers license living abroad

Tags: driving-license

I currently live in Austria. I would like to keep my US drivers license. I don't mind going to the US to renew but I want to make sure I can renew them before I take this trip just to find out that I can't. Does anyone have suggestions or answers, it would be much appreciated . Thanks

Syrena.

Comment: Strictly speaking in most states (if not all) you are not supposed to renew your driver's license unless you are a resident of that state.  The specific rules depend on the state.  What state issued your driver's license?

Comment: California in particular used to be quite happy if you kept your license current since they'd sometimes use that fact and the address on the license to argue you remained a resident for tax purposes in your absence. Their aim to qualify the license for REAL ID act purposes has recently made them much more fussy about determining you actually live where you say you do, though.

Comment: If you do maintain a California address, you can [renew by mail](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/wcm/connect/817d879a-e709-45a1-9503-57622ec808b4/dl410.pdf?MOD=AJPERES). Of course, the new license will be sent there.